# Using Beautiful Soup how can I return this value and use it as an integer?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is not the same as extract number from a string as beautiful soup returns a beautiful soup object.

I have a local HTML file and I have used BeautifulSoup to Print the text between the pre code tags. This is my current code.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('/home/stats/trade_result.html', 'r')

s = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(s,"lxml")
pre = soup.find_all('pre')
print(pre)

This is what gets printed out:

```
last balance: xxxxxx (-0.07%)
buy hold: xxxxxx (-0.08%)
vs. buy hold: 0.01%
2 trades over 8 days (avg 0.25 trades/day)
win/loss: 0/1
error rate: 100.00%
```

]

How can I return the number (2 in this example) that is before "trades over" on the forth line down and use it as an integer later in my program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that is always the fourth line inside the `pre` tag:

```
result = int(pre[0].text.split('\n')[3].split('trades over')[0])
```

Outputs:

```
2
```

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider marking the answer as correct.

Comment: sorry I m just a beginner - I thought this worked but it was wrong output. I get error message , line 10, in <module>
    result = int(pre.split('\n')[3].split('trades over')[0])
AttributeError: 'ResultSet' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I have also tried just using find instead of find all but get this error line 10, in <module>
    result = int(pre.split('\n')[3].split('trades over')[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: See the edited answer.

Comment: Still getting an error TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: This is my code - thanks for help from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

f = open('/home/trade_result.html', 'r')

s = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(s,"lxml")
pre = soup.find_all('pre')
#result = int(pre.split('\n')[3].split('trades over')[0]) old answer
result = int(pre[0].split('\n')[3].split('trades over')[0])

Comment: See edited answer, I missed a `.text` call.

Comment: thanks drec4s - that definitely works now, much appreciated, iIwill mark it answered .